# Can i modify data inside a NSArray compared to NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have found many discussions about `NSMutableArray` vs `NSArray`.
It's very interesting and i understand that you cannot add or delete objects inside a NSArray

But is it possible to change objects in a `NSArray` ?

I mean, if i have a `NSArray` of `NSNumber`, can i change the `NSNumber` in the `NSArray` or should i use a `NSMutableArray` to be able to modify values of objects in the `NSArray`  ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NSArray` does not let you **exchange** the elements (nor append or remove them). If you had an `NSArray` of *mutable* objects, say `NSMutableString`s you could modify the objects without changing the array.

Since Cocoa does not contain a mutable variant of `NSNumber` you cannot do that with number objects, though.

Example:

```
// immutable array, immutable elements: no way to change anything.
NSArray *array1 = @[@1, @2, @3];

// immutable array of mutable elements:
NSArray *array2 = @[[@"1" mutableCopy], [@"2" mutableCopy], [@"3" mutableCopy]];
NSLog(@"Step 1: %@", array2); // prints "1, 2, 3"

// now we change one of the elements of the immutable array:
[array2[0] appendString:@".1"];
NSLog(@"Step 2: %@", array2); // prints "1.1, 2, 3"
```

Long story short:

> Can i modify data inside an NSArray?

Yes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer .. but i'm really bad with this Cocoa notion of Mutable/non mutable variables. If NSNumber is not mutable : i can't declare a NSNumber with a doubleValue of 12.3 and after that set the same variable to 42.3 ?

Comment: Your confusion comes from the old C pointer/pointee concept: The variable is only a pointer. It can point to any object and you can always change the variable to point to another object (if you did not declare the variable `const`). On the other hand also the pointed-to value can change. That's what Objective-C's mutable objects are about.